# UML class diagram implementing Registration for login

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram

I am trying to model a class diagram model where a user needs to login to a Java swing application. The user would have to register before being able to login. Here I have shown this through the composition relationship. I am not sure if this is correct. I feel Registration could be a generalisation of user and named "New user" but if this is the case I feel I would need to make another generalisation called "Returning user" but the User class and the the generalisation "Returning user" would have the exact same methods and attributes and so I assume this is wrong. I was wondering if someone could help me understand this part of the class diagram. Thanks in advance[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I feel Registration could be a generalisation of user and named "New user" but if this is the case I feel I would need to make another generalisation called "Returning user" but the User class and the the generalisation "Returning user" would have the exact same methods and attributes and so I assume this is wrong

Yes this is wrong, a *Registration* is not a *User* nor the reverse, so there is no generalization between these two classes.

Your can have the compositions you indicate, but why the classes *User* and *Register* have the attributes *email* and *password* ?. Do you want to save the initial values in *Register* while the current values (can be the same) are in *User* or the reverse ?

Of course the class checking the password must have access to the (current) password whatever the way for.

Why the class *Admin* has the attribute *adminName*, the name is already managed by *User* and *Register*

All your attributes are *String*, for the dates/durations this is strange.

Your operations do not have parameters, some of them certainly need parameter(s) to work

As I understand the class *Register* is not only used during the registration, its name is not very clear then, *Registration* which is closed is more clear

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Register & user have email and password because the user before becoming a user would need to register and to register they would require a email and password. This email and password is stored to then be used and checked against when the user tries to log in. I added adminName to Admin just to add a property for now. I am not sure if in a class diagram it is okay to show specialisation without unique attributes. I've used String since it's all I know to store that specific data e.g. registerDate I use string. Not sure how else to store it in Java.

Comment: `the user before becoming a user` the instance of the class is created when registering or do you create only an instance of *Register* first then when confirm the instance of *User* ? Note the multiplicities indicate both instances are created at the same time, and in that case to distinguish a registered user and a verified user better to just use a boolean flag, no need to duplicate login and password.

Comment: Thanks for getting back again, appreciate it. I am trying to show that a registration form needs to be filled before someone becomes a user. The relationship is showing that user relies on register existence in order to exist (black diamond) I feel this might be wrong. When you launch the program it will have username and password and a button to Register or Login. The person registers if not a user already, this is stored in database. If user already then they just login. This is what I am trying to show but I've become super confused